# Calling async method from MVVM property

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm implementing my own version of auto-complete in a view model in my Xamarin Forms 5 app.

I need to call an `async` look up function from the `Keyword` MVVM property. Not sure if I'm handling it right. See below:

```
string keyword { get; set; }
ObservableRangeCollection<string> suggestions = new ObservableRangeCollection<string>();
public string Keyword
{
   get => keyword;
   set
   {
      if(keyword == value)
         return;

      keyword = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();

      // If keyword has at least 3 characters, get suggestions
      if(keyword.length > 2)
         GetSuggestions(keyword).Wait();
   }
}

ObservableRangeCollection<string> Suggestions
{
   get => suggestions;
   set
   {
      if(sugggestions == value)
         return;

      suggestions = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}

async Task GetSuggestions(string searchKeyword)
{
   var result = await _myApiService.GetSuggestions(searchKeyword);
   if(result != null)
   {
      Suggestions = new ObservableRangeCollection(result);
      OnPropertyChanged(Suggestions);
   }
}
```

I'd appreciate any corrections or suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://reactiveui.net and the example code on the home page. There is also a complete [example](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/compelling-example) for a nuget search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely [don't want to block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) here (as explained on my blog). More generally, you don't want to block the UI, especially when your users are interacting with it (i.e., typing).

Instead, use a pattern like [async data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding) to (synchronously) *start* the operation, and then *update* your UI when the results come in.

E.g., using `NotifyTask<T>` from [here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm/blob/d90b2a0e4792a450549f3770e7886275c3ccb0fc/future/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs):

```
string keyword { get; set; }
NotifyTask<List<string>> suggestions;
public string Keyword
{
   get => keyword;
   set
   {
      if (keyword == value)
         return;

      keyword = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();

      // If keyword has at least 3 characters, get suggestions
      if (keyword.length > 2)
         suggestions = NotifyTask.Create(GetSuggestionsAsync(keyword));
   }
}

NotifyTask<List<string>> Suggestions
{
   get => suggestions;
}

async Task<List<string>> GetSuggestionsAsync(string searchKeyword)
{
   return await _myApiService.GetSuggestions(searchKeyword);
}
```

Then, instead of data-binding to `Suggestions` as a collection of `string`, data-bind to `Suggestions.Result` instead. You can also data-bind to `Suggestions.IsCompleted` (or `Suggestions.IsNotCompleted`) to show a loading/busy indicator, and `Suggestions.IsFaulted` to show an error message.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I understand the underlying problem but need to dive deeper to understand `NotifyTask<T>`.

Comment: Sorry but I think I need a bit more hand holding here. Where does `PropertyChangedEventArgsCache` come from? I couldn't find any reference to it anywhere, except in your repo. I also tried following your article on Microsoft Documents but wasn't able to get the code to work because in that article, you don't have `Create` method in `NotifyTaskCompletion`.

Comment: @Sam: The code in the GitHub repo is an updated version of the code in that article. All the supporting types should be in the GitHub repo. `PropertyChangedEventArgsCache` isn't strictly necessary; it just avoids unnecessary garbage in MVVM apps.

Comment: First, thank you for the solution. I was able to get the code working using the older version from your article but not the newer version in your repo. It's primarily because I don't fully understand the code even though I understand what `NotifyTask` does. I need to deepen my understanding of the underlying concepts. I see you wrote quite a few articles on async starting in 2012 and I read a few and will continue to read them. Any other source you can recommend? This is the deeper plumbing most developers don't bother with and this maybe my opportunity. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sam Those three async mvvm articles are still relevant, although IMO the async data binding one is best. You may find some more general async resources helpful such as my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [async best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). For an interesting but more complex take on UIs, check out [reactive UI](https://www.reactiveui.net/).